# Getting the number of selected entries in Action using Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a Admin Panel using Laravel Nova. I know Laravel Nova is a new technology. Now I am having a bit of problem using [Nova actions](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/actions/defining-actions.html#overview). I need to get the number of selected entries for the action. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I selected two entries for the action. In Nova action class, in fields method of action class, I'd like to get the number of selected entries.

```
class ActivateUsers extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {

        }
    }

    public function fields()
    {
         //Here I need to get the number of selected entries
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to the fields method of the Action and the comment in it. How can I get the number of selected entries in the fields method of the action class?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the operation this way:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    $models->count(); // number of selected entries
}
```